# Find dropbox path not working on some computers

Tags: regex, excel, vba, dropbox

The code below is causing some trouble. I have used it on 5 computers and it works fine. My company has now brought 5 more computers and now it doesn't want to work on the new ones. It is supposed to find the dropbox path using the JSON file.

```
Function DownloadF()
Dim RegEx As Object
Dim MatchColl As Object
Dim DataLine As String
Dim DropboxPath
Const FileNum = 1 ' Assumes no other files are open!!

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.IgnoreCase = False


Open Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Dropbox\info.json" For Input As #FileNum

Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
   Line Input #FileNum, DataLine  ' read in data 1 line at a time
   ' decide what to do with dataline,
   ' depending on what processing you need to do for each case
Loop

Close #FileNum

RegEx.Pattern = "^.*""path"": ""([^""]*).*"

DropboxPath = Replace(RegEx.Replace(DataLine, "$1"), "", "")

' If there are multiple dropbox accounts on this machine, this will
' only get the first one

DownloadF = DropboxPath & Range("Pathway")

End Function
```

[image: Working Code]

The above picture is what it is supposed to show but the below is what it returns.

[image: Non-working]

All the settings are the same for excel. Has anyone came across this problem?